PHP Laravel, error screen shows sensitive information
I have a PHP application using Laravel, whenever there is an error, the system will open a screen containing the error details with db connection details, the database name even the password. How can I prevent the application from showing this sensitive information.
Thank you

Is there anything specific in https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/errors you're having trouble with?

APP_DEBUG=false

If the APP_DEBUG value in .env is true, all details appear in the error message.

When you have your app in the production mode make APP_ENV=production and APP_DEBUG=FALSE to prevent Laravel from exposing sensitive information.
